# Error in C; segmentation fault with method

Tags: c

So i'm having a segmentation error with this piece of code and i don't know why. i thought it had to do with the fact that I was using NULL wrong(?) but i don't think thats it. .I tried adding more error messages to see if I can go anywhere with that but I still get the same error /:

```
char* lookup(Dictionary D, char* k){
   Node N = D->head;

   if(D == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: calling lookup() on null Dictionary");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   while(N!=NULL){
    if(strcmp(N->key,k)==0){
      return N->value;
      break;
    }
    N = N->next;
   }
   return NULL;
}


void insert(Dictionary D, char* k, char* v){
  // Node N = D->head;

   if(D==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: inserting on a null Dictionary\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if(lookup(D,k)!=NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "already existing\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   else{

     if(D->numItems==0){
      Node N;
      N = newNode(k,v);
      D->head = N;
      D->numItems++;
     }

    //if there is only a head node, add node after it
   else{
    Node S = D->head;
      while(S!=NULL) {
        S = S->next;
      }
      S->next = newNode(k,v);
    }
      D->numItems++;
   }

 }
```

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `Node N = D->head;  if(D == NULL){`  1) variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like `N` and `D` are meaningless.  2) if `D` is NULL, then accessing `D->head` is undefined behavior and will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY opening brace '{'.  Unindent before EVERY closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) include struct & typedef definitions so readers can understand what is being reference.  3) use meaningful variable (and parameter) names 4) post the bodies of all your functions

Comment: in function: `lookup()`, regarding: `return N->value;`  per the variable naming, this would indicate a integer is being returned rather than a `char*`  Always post the data definitions

Answer (score 1):

In the lookup() function

```
 Node N = D->head;
 if(D == NULL){
```

You have already accessed D before checking if it is NULL. This could result in a NULL pointer accesss and core dump.

In the insert() function:

```
 while(S!=NULL) {
    S = S->next;
  }
  // You are guaranteed that S is now == NULL, so the
  // next line is a NULL pointer access.
  S->next = newNode(k,v);
```

You need to keep the last item so you can say `last->next = newNode(k, v);`

Also: if there are 0 items in the collection, doesn't `numItems` get incremented twice? Hard to tell because of the bad code formatting...

Additional comments:

- You obviously have typedefs for Dictionary and Node that hide the fact they are pointers. Don't do that. It makes it confusing for anyone reading the code.
- A very common convention is to start types with a capital letter but not variables, so `D`, `N` and `S` are all bad names. You can do better than 1 character names anyway. How about `dict` and `node`